# change original value before reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an hidden input: `<input type=hidden id="abc" name=abc value=111></input>`

```
var val= $('#abc').val();
if(abc != ""){
    alert(abc);  // when page RE-loads - On Firefox the alert is "" but on Chrome/I.e. it is still "111"
}
```

JS:

```
alert($('#abc').val());//////////////////  alert: "111" on all browsers
$('#abc').attr("value", "");
//$('#abc').val('');  // same result
alert($('#abc').val());//////////////////  alert: "" on all browsers
window.location.reload(); //Re-load the page
```

On Firefox: it works as expected and it alert "" (empty) after the code `window.location.reload();`.
But on Chrome and I.E. it always alert "111" (original value) although I set the value to empty string ("").

It like it use the original value after the page loads.

Is there something I can do here?

Thanks
Mike

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do as the question isn't clear at all. That said, use `.val('')` to clear the value, not `attr()`

Comment: You want persistant data client side?! So use any cookie/localStorage/sessionStorage

Comment: I also used `$('#abc').val('');` to clear the data but on load it alerting "111" again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using cookie.
I defined a cookie with timeout on the first page load and then I could check if this cookie already set.